# Confused on creating new directories and changing directories (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, directory

When I changed the current directory path of `main.m` to `newDir` why does it still say that there are no files in `newDir`? Also I ran this program multiple times with no errors. Does that mean I ended up creating multiple `newDir`?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *newDir = @"newDir";
        NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        if ([manager createDirectoryAtPath:newDir withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:NULL] == NO) {
            NSLog(@"couldnt create new directory");
            return 1;
        }

        if ([manager changeCurrentDirectoryPath: newDir] == NO) {
            NSLog(@"couldnt change directory path");
            return 2;
        }

        NSLog(@"%@", [manager currentDirectoryPath]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:newDir error:NULL]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2012-08-07 10:27:20.428 Test[853:707] /Users/ss/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-bfrqtnrhaafmdzghoyirjnfqjbfc/Build/Products/Debug/newDir
2012-08-07 10:36:47.832 Test[885:707] (null)
```

Comment: It will be null, there is nothing in the directory.

Comment: @Helium3 -- I would expect the result to be an empty array, not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to `main.m` does not play into what happens when you run your program: the only question is whether the directory has any files or not, and from the log it appears that it doesn't.

To create some files in the directory, run these commands in the terminal window:

```
touch /Users/ss/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-bfrqtnrhaafmdzghoyirjnfqjbfc/Build/Products/Debug/newDir/quick.txt
touch /Users/ss/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-bfrqtnrhaafmdzghoyirjnfqjbfc/Build/Products/Debug/newDir/brown.txt
touch /Users/ss/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-bfrqtnrhaafmdzghoyirjnfqjbfc/Build/Products/Debug/newDir/fox.txt
```

This will create three empty files. Now run your program, and see if it discovers the newly created `txt` files; it should.

On your second question, the operating system would not let you create multiple file system objects with identical names, so the answer is no, you created only one `newDir`.

Comment: @dashblinkenlight I'm sorry I never programmed before, and I'm finding the whole process of working with files very confusing. Is changing the path name equivalent to changing where the file is located?

Comment: @stumped How do you change the path name of a file?

Comment: When the `[manager changeCurrentDirectoryPath: newDir]` was called didn't it change the pathname by adding the `newDir` at the end?

Comment: @stumped Yes, it did change the current path for all operations that use relative paths. So when you call `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:`, the current path will be prepended to `newDir`, because it is not an absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're ignoring errors on your `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath` call, it's entirely possible that the call is failing -- hence the null.

Without looking at references, it appears that you're looking for directory `.../newDir/newDir`, a directory that likely does not exist.

In any event, since `newDir` is new it wouldn't contain any entries (other than . and ..).